# How to remove raster parts by area

Tags: r

Somebody nows how to remove some parts of the raster based on area?

```
library(raster)
# create some raster data
r <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=12)
set.seed(0)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*0.7 )
rc <- clump(r)
```

In this example I have some fragments with 3 cels, 4 cells and 5 cells, but How can I remove the path with 2 cels?

Comment: Do you want to clip your `raster`?

Comment: nop, I dont have a shapefile to clip my raster, I just want to remove the fragments inside this file with count cells less than a specific number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
r[is.na(match(values(rc), (1:maxValue(rc))[table(getValues(rc))>2]))] <- NA
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, though.

---

`table` tabulates the number of cells for each clump ID. Those greater than 2 are identified and these IDs are pulled out of the vector `(1:maxValue(rc))`. Then, cells with these IDs are found in the clump raster using `match`. Those not found return `NA`, so I check for them with `is.na`. Finally, the corresponding cells in the original raster are replaced with `NA`.